# Validate methods don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use [THAT](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin to validate forms, but i have a problem with [rangelenght](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rangelength-method/) methods. Dont work for me. I try copy-paste but that still dont work. I dont have any error in console. After send form with only one character i see in console "ads" I look in plugin code, method exist. Did you know what be a reason?

Here is my code:

```
$( "#login-form" ).validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [6, 20]
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        console.log('ads');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" action="index.html" id="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Adres email" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasło" required="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button> 
    <a href="#">
        <small>Zapomniałeś hasła?</small>
    </a>
</form>
```

Comment: try `range` instead of `rangelength`

Comment: That not that. Still dont work :(

Comment: does your required validation works?

Comment: Yes. Required and email works fine, only that rangelength dont.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: You misspelled `rangelength` in your question, but got it right in the posted code. Check the real code.

Comment: `minlength` works fine

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xetsbbjr/2/

Comment: even for me http://jsfiddle.net/zpx0ccwf/2/
can you show us your example in fiddle

Comment: me too working fine.

Comment: For me dont work :( http://jsfiddle.net/xetsbbjr/3/

Comment: @Barmar Its copy and paste

Comment: You're missing `name="password"` in the password field. The validation plugin uses the name, not the ID.

Comment: You need to include the relevant HTML markup within your OP.   The solution to your question is impossible to know without it.

Comment: **Quote @Braj**:  *"try `range` instead of `rangelength` ... `minlength` works fine"* ~ why?  [`rangelength` is a perfectly valid method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rangelength-method/).

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot! Beer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `name="email"` and `name="password"` to the input fields. The validation plugin matches the elements of `rules` using the `name` attribute, not `id`.

The `email` and `required` validations worked because the plugin looks at the `type` and `required` attributes as well. So if a field has `type="email"`, it's equivalent to `email: true` in the rules.

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" action="index.html" id="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Adres email" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasło" required="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button> 
    <a href="#">
        <small>Zapomniałeś hasła?</small>
    </a>
</form>
```

[Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xetsbbjr/6/)